# Subdivide string and return object

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, regex, javascript-objects

i'm working on a tool and got stuck.

I'm accessing the stylesheet object of a website and only want to get the "CSSFontFaceRule". I worked that out, but the output in my returned object is a huge string. I want to subdivide the string into an on object.
I also created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9eoytc6v/1/

This is my status quo:

```
@font-face {font-family: "Test-Book";
src: 
    url("https://fontserver.xyz/test.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("https://fontserver.xyz/test.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("https://fontserver.xyz/test.woff") format("woff"),
    url("https://fontserver.xyz/test.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("https://fontserver.xyz/test.svg#Test-Book") format("svg");
}
```

```javascript
let fonts = {};

function getFontPairs(obj) {
  let object = obj || {},
    stylesheet = document.styleSheets,
    rule = null,
    length = stylesheet.length,
    j;
  while (0 <= --length) {
    rule = stylesheet[length].rules || stylesheet[length].cssRules || [];
    j = rule.length;
    while (0 <= --j) {
      if (rule[j].constructor.name === "CSSFontFaceRule") {
        let sourcesString = rule[j].style.src;
        let re = /\s*(?:,|$)\s*/;
        let sources = sourcesString.split(re);
        let final = [];

        sources.forEach(function(element){
        let reg = /[ ,]+/;
        let srcArray = element.split(reg);
        srcArray = srcArray.reverse();
        final.push(srcArray);
        });

       object[rule[j].style.fontFamily] = final;


      }
    }
  }
  return object;
}

getFontPairs(fonts);
console.log(fonts);
```

I tried to work with arrays but my output is a little bit messy: 
[Current array solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwpk8.png)

Instead i want to achieve something like this:
[Expected object solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLZ56.png)

So i'm not good at RegEx for now and i want to strip off the `url("")` and the `format("")`as well.
I appreciate any help. Maybe someone can help out with a more productive version of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just match the url and the format from each source string. A simple regex will do, the regex just matches what inside the double or single quotes, example of the regex to match the url:

```
/url\(.(.+?).\)/
```

Which means match anything between `url(.` and `.)`. The parens are escaped so that the regex won't look at them as a group. The `.` (any character) to stand for the quotes (doubles or single). The `(.+?)` is what we are interessted in, the url, this is using the non-gready mode `?` so that it will match as few characters as possible, otherwise you may end up with a url like: `https://fontserver.xyz/test.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype` which matches from the first quote to the second (goes beyond the url and enters the format territory).

Then, to construct the object, just `reduce` the sources into one like:

```
let sourcesObj = sources.reduce((acc, source) => {       // for each source
  let format = source.match(/format\(.(.+?).\)/)[1],     // get the format
      url = source.match(/url\(.(.+?).\)/)[1];           // and the url

  acc[format] = { format, url };                         // add them to the sourcesObj under the key format ({ format, url } is short for { format: format, url: url })
  return acc;
}, {});
```

**Full Code:**

```js
function getFontPairs() {
  let object = {},
    stylesheet = document.styleSheets,
    rule = null,
    length = stylesheet.length,
    j;
  while (0 <= --length) {
    rule = stylesheet[length].rules || stylesheet[length].cssRules || [];
    j = rule.length;
    while (0 <= --j) {
      if (rule[j].constructor.name === "CSSFontFaceRule") {
        let sourcesString = rule[j].style.src;
        let sources = sourcesString.split(/\s*,\s*/);

        let sourcesObj = sources.reduce((acc, source) => {
          let format = source.match(/format\(.(.+?).\)/)[1],
              url = source.match(/url\(.(.+?).\)/)[1];

          acc[format] = { format, url };
          return acc;
        }, {});

        object[rule[j].style.fontFamily] = sourcesObj;
      }
    }
  }
  return object;
}

let fonts = getFontPairs();
console.log(fonts);
```

**Note:** A more sophisticated alternative to the url and format regex would be:

```
/url(\s*["'](.+?)["']\s*)/
```

Which handles cases where there are blank spaces like `url(  "..."  )` and look for quotes (either `"` or `'`) to be safe. Same thing could be applied to the format regex.

---

**EDIT:**

If some source has a missing field, then just check if the format and url regexes did actually match something before accessing the group `[1]`:

```
let sourcesObj = sources.reduce((acc, source) => {
  let format = source.match(/format\(.(.+?).\)/),
      url = source.match(/url\(.(.+?).\)/);

  if(format && url) {                                       // if and only if the two regexes matched what they are intended for
    acc[format[1]] = { format: format[1], url: url[1] };    // add the current source to 'sourcesObj' (notice the '[1]' is used after we've made sure that neither 'format' nor 'url' are 'null')
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
```

**EDIT 2:**

When `format` is missing, replace by `"Unknown"`:

```
let sourcesObj = sources.reduce((acc, source) => {
  let format = source.match(/format\(.(.+?).\)/),
      url = source.match(/url\(.(.+?).\)/)[1];

  format = format? format[1]: "Unknown";

  acc = { format, url };
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: Your're awesome man! But if I try this on a live website i always get the Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`. Do you have a clue for this?

Comment: @thetw Can you console log the sources string and manually check the one that caused the error? It probably doesn't have a `format` or `url` field.

Comment: You were right. If tried it on a website which has both attributes in the styles definition and it worked like a charm. But is there a way to prevent the script from not working where one of the attributes isn't there? Because my ugly array solution works on some pages (i got an url and a format in the array) where your object solution won't work...

Comment: @thetw Okey-dokey! What should be the outcome of this scenarion? Should I just skip the current source all together, or should I make it an `"unknown"` format? BTW which field is missing, the `format` or the `url`?

Comment: @thetw Check out the **EDIT**. The editted version skips over the source that have a missing field. If you want to handle it in another way, please do tell me.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, i had to refocuse my project scope. Now i think that skipping a source won't be the perfect solution, because i want to know that there is a element found by the script, anyway if there is a source or a format. So how about a solution where the script places the string "unknown" into the output object, when there is one parameter missing?

Comment: @thetw Which parameter is missing? Could they both be missing or is the `format` the only field that could be missing?

Comment: The `format` field could be missing when the font is base64 encoded, because the format is implemented in the url: `url("data:application/x-font-woff;base64`. We need to cover this case...Is it possible to extract the data type out of the string and set is as format? Then set the full base64 string as url?